# Proving that $SU(2)$ acts transitively on $S^2$ w.r.t. adjoint action

Tags: differential-geometry, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, homogeneous-spaces

I've been assigned the following exercise:

> Prove that $S^2$ is a homogeneous space w.r.t. the adjoint action of $SU(2)$.

We're obviously referring to $Ad:G\to\operatorname{Aut}(\mathfrak{g}), Ad_g:X\mapsto gXg^{-1}$. I believe that what has been asked is to consider the isomorphism of Lie algebras $$\mathfrak{su}(2)=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}it & -\overline{z}\\z &-it\end{pmatrix} \ \middle\vert\ t\in\Bbb{R},\ z\in\Bbb{C}\right\} \cong\Bbb{R}^3$$ (with the vector product as Lie bracket), and interpreting $\{X\in\mathfrak{su}(2)\mid \det X=1\}$ as $S^2$.

I feel like the difficult part is using specifically the *adjoint* action of $SU(2)$.

---

**What I tried:** we're basically asked to prove that $Ad$ acts transitively on $\mathfrak{su}(2)$, i.e. for all $X,Y\in\mathfrak{su}(2)$ there is some $A\in SU(2)$ s.t. $AXA^\dagger=Y$ (here $A^{-1}=A^\dagger$ denotes the conjugate transpose matrix). I tried playing around with decompositions such as
$$SU(2)\ni\begin{pmatrix}\alpha&-\overline{\beta}\\ \beta&\overline{\alpha}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}e^{i\theta}&0\\0&e^{-i\theta}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}t&-\overline{\beta}e^{-i\theta}\\ \beta e^{i\theta}&t\end{pmatrix},\quad \alpha=te^{i\theta}.$$
Unfortunately, I keep getting stuck. I even tried choosing one particular $Y$ and finding explicitly an $A$ in function of $X$, but I've had no luck with this method either so far. For example:
$$\begin{pmatrix}\alpha&-\overline{\beta}\\ \beta&\overline{\alpha}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}it & -\overline{z}\\z &-it\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\alpha&-\overline{\beta}\\ \beta&\overline{\alpha}\end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}Z&-\overline{W}\\ W&\overline{Z}\end{pmatrix},$$
$$ Z=(|\alpha|^2-|\beta|^2)it+\alpha\beta\overline{z}-\overline{\alpha\beta}z$$
$$ W=\overline{\alpha}^2z+\beta^2\overline{z}+(\overline{\alpha}\beta) it $$

I wonder if there's a simpler (or more elegant) way to solve this problem, or if I'm just awful at this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The adjoint representation of $SU(2)$ corresponds to the double cover $SU(2) \to SO(3)$; that is, this question is secretly asking you to prove that $SO(3)$ acts transitively on $S^2$, which is geometrically clear.

Comment: So there's no easy way to do this directly, without passing through $SO(3)$?

Comment: I didn't say that! But I think the $SO(3)$ argument is reasonably clean and easy. You can also calculate explicitly (using the geometric argument to guide you) a rotation about a suitable axis that will send any particular point to any other, then lift that rotation to $SU(2)$ in a way that doesn't explicitly require mentioning $SO(3)$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Sorry, one more question: if this is the case, why can I assume that the composition of the double cover and adjoint rep of $SO(3)$ would be the same as the adjoint rep of $SU(2)$?

Comment: A covering map of Lie groups induces an isomorphism on Lie algebras so the adjoint representations of the two are always compatible.

Comment: So I'm using the fact that $SU(2)\xrightarrow{Ad} Aut(\mathfrak{su(2)})$ is the same map as $$SU(2)\xrightarrow{Ad} SO(3)\xrightarrow{Ad} Aut(\mathfrak{so(3)}) \xrightarrow{\cong} Aut(\mathfrak{su(2)}),$$
am I right? The composition of $Ad$'s threw me off for a minute

Comment: Yes, that's right. It is maybe a little misleading to call the map $SU(2) \to SO(3)$ by the name "$\text{Ad}$." It is just a fact that the adjoint representation is not faithful and factors through $SO(3)$; generally, the adjoint representation of a connected Lie group $G$ factors through $G/Z(G)$ (the "adjoint form"). So you're taking the image factorization of the adjoint map.